# How to format a json string?

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to convert

```
{"name":"john","age":22,"class":"mca"}
```

to

```
"{\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":22,\"class\":\"mca\"}"
```

How can I do this using Gson library? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the JSON `String` you can just use `toJson` on it like this:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = "{\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":22,\"class\":\"mca\"}";

    System.out.println("original: "+json);

    String escaped = gson.toJson(json);
    System.out.println("escaped: "+escaped);
```

Output:

```
original: {"name":"john","age":22,"class":"mca"}
escaped: "{\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":22,\"class\":\"mca\"}"
```

Comment: That was a really neat trick I would never have thought of, good job sir!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of online tools that can help you do so, here are few ...

- https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html
- https://codebeautify.org/java-escape-unescape

Programmatically, if you have input as JSON Object then you can just print the JSONObject using `toString()`; you would need escape characters in JSON string only if you are using it as a string itself in the code mostly for testing (UT or FT).

But if you still insist on escaped JSON String then you can use string `replaceAll()` on `JSONObject toString()` and have all double quotes replaced with escape character and double quotes.